# How to have a main object in my json data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, ruby-on-rails-4

Question, I am loading data from my db to my local redis server I want this data to have a main object like "animals" for some reason it always save it with out a main object. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is my json data

```
[
    {
        "what_animal": "Lion",
        "create_date": "March-14-16",
    },
    {
        "what_animal": "Zebra",
        "create_date": "March-15-16",
    },
    {
        "what_animal": "Monkey",
        "create_date": "March-16-16",
    }
]
```

Here is what I would like it to look like

```
{
  "animals": [
    {
        "what_animal": "Lion",
        "create_date": "March-14-16",
    },
    {
        "what_animal": "Zebra",
        "create_date": "March-15-16",
    },
    {
        "what_animal": "Monkey",
        "create_date": "March-16-16",
    }
 ]
}
```

Here is my method to get and update my redis server with the data in my db

```
def self.fetch_animals
  animals = $redis.get("all_animals")
  if animals.nil?
    animals = Animals.all.order('create_date ASC').to_json
    $redis.set("all_animals", animals)
    $redis.expire("all_animals", 1.hour.to_i)
  end
  animals = JSON.load animals
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this line:

```
$redis.set("all_animals", animals)
```

to this:

```
$redis.set("all_animals", { animals: animals }.to_json)
```

Comment: That worked somewhat but now when I view its in plain text format not json @spickermann

Comment: @Snowman41288: Sorry, I missed the [`to_json` part](https://github.com/redis/redis-rb#storing-objects).